# inline assembly code style - what does the number mean?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, x86-64, inline-assembly

I am relatively new to assembly and do not get the following line. 
What does the 8 in the brackets do? I do not understand what does this way of writing in the brackets mean.. Could someone help me?

```
movq %%rdx, (%1, %%r8, 8)\n\t
```

Comment: This is a SIB (scale/index/base) addressing mode.  Refer to your CPU's manual for details.  The GNU assembler manual covers this, too.  You won't get far with assembly if you don't read manuals.

Comment: This may help: http://www.imada.sdu.dk/Courses/DM18/Litteratur/IntelnATT.htm

Comment: %1 would be referencing constraint 1 (second constraint)which would have been a register picked by the compiler. It is being used as the base of the address calculation. It is same as 0+[%1 + r8 * 8]

Comment: Thanks for answering. Doesn't it (%1) refer to one of the input values. I have input values written at the end like :"r" (X), "r" (Y) , .. and the corresponding %1 should be a value between 0 and 7 .. And what is an 8?